# Generate header/declaration file with golang - all in one file?

Tags: typescript, go

I am looking to auto-generate some Golang declaration files based on some .json data. Ideally I could put all the declaration/header data into one file. But the way that Golang packages/namespacing works, I doubt I can do that.

Instead of Golang, using TypeScript, I can put a lot of TS types/declarations in one file, using namespaces like so:

```
export namespace Entities {
  export namespace Foo {

    export namespace GET {
      export namespace Basic {

        export interface Req { }
        export interface Res { }

      }

    }

    export namespace PUT {
      export namespace Basic {

        export interface Req { }
        export interface Res { }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

my question is - is there a way to do something like this with golang? Or will I have to use separate files/folders to achieve separate namespaces?

The only thing I know how to do is put them in separate files:

```
entities/
    foo/
      get/
      put/
      post/
      delete/
```

and then in each of those folders, something like:

```
package get
type Basic struct {
     Req struct {}
     Res struct {}
}
```

but that doesn't achieve what I want unfortunately, because I cannot reference the Basic.Req or Basic.Res types directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang logically organizes code by packages.  Each directory is a different package.  If you want to generate structs in distinct packages, they must reside in different directories.

You may want to organize your generated libraries by their language styles.  The `http` package has good suggestions on how to organize a library with network calls.

Comment: link to http package ... on github? Imma newb.

Comment: See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http. I'd also suggest taking a look at https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin or https://echo.labstack.com.

Remember too that you have to create your struct before you can reference it. Typically this would be something like:

    ```func NewBasic (req *http.Request, res *http.Response) Basic {
        return &Basic{
            Req: req,
            Res: res,
        }
    }```

That code doesn't actually return a struct (you'd have to create a new Req/Res struct before assigning it to Basic), but hopefully it gets you started.